# Azure Developer specific Roles

Tags: azure

I am new to Azure and want to understand, who define and setup developer roles.

Ideally what roles developer teams should have to start ?
Who defines and assign these roles to developer ?

Is it something similar like we define NetOps, Secops, AppDevOps,PlatformOps team ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That really depends on your team, size, culture and development style. For example for smaller teams ideally the CTOs manage these sort of things. If you are service/ project oriented company then the roles will be scoped to each service/ project or if you are a product based company then roles/ groups will be different based on the responsibilities and your in team processes. So, in simple words there not a direct answer or silver bullet for this. It usually depends on the team dynamics.

Comment: @AliKhan : Thanks for explaining this. Can you please provide some example ?

Comment: E-g in one product based startup I worked with, I used to handle all these roles initially. We started with basic web application and Api roles related to development, qa and product team for the management of different operations in azure devops. But as we scaled with respect to our technical solution, we employed dedicated teams for these functions which started with basic IT management/ Ops team, then devOps team then we included security and data in that as well. And all of these teams work in collaboration to get the max productivity possible.